# Automatically add unique version numbers to JS, CSS files in NetBeans when deploying WARs

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, ant, web-deployment

I am trying to figure out how other web developers deal with with the issue of older cached versions of JS and CSS files when deploying new versions of a web application.

If I don't change the names of these files, then users might see weird behavior if they get a cached older version of the JS or CSS.  I could update the filenames with a version number manually, but that would make checking the file's history in version control messy.

I feel like the perfect system would be the IDE/build system (I'm using NetBeans) automatically adding a datetime string to these filenames, e.g. renaming *style.css* to *style.201503131432.css*, when the WAR file is built although then of course all references to the file (e.g. in JSP files importing them) would have to be updated automatically as well.  I expected to find a NetBeans plugin to do something like this, but I haven't been able to.

Am I totally off-base with how other developers handle this problem?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files) for how to force browsers to load the fresh version.